# make git command line colorful using puppet

Tags: git, puppet

I am trying to make git command line colorful using puppet and getting error. what am i missing?

```
exec { 'make-git-color':
  command => '/usr/bin/git config --global color.ui auto',
  logoutput => 'on_failure',
  user      => 'vagrant',
  timeout   => 1200,
  require   => Package['git']
}
```

Error is:

```
 /Exec[make-git-color]/returns: fatal: $HOME not set
Error: '/usr/bin/git config --global color.ui auto' returned 128 instead of one of [0]
```

command running directly works fine. `/usr/bin/git config --global color.ui auto`

But I need to do it via puppet.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, $HOME is not set. You need to change your code to something like this, to set the missing environment variable:

```
exec { 'make-git-color':
  command     => '/usr/bin/git config --global color.ui auto',
  logoutput   => 'on_failure',
  user        => 'vagrant',
  environment => 'HOME=/home/vagrant',
  require     => Package['git']
}
```

That will work (I tested it). Docs for passing environment variables to exec are [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/types/exec.html#exec-attribute-environment).

Notice I also removed the timeout, which wasn't required.

If you need to also ensure idempotence, per the comments below, change it to:

```
exec { 'make-git-color':
  command     => 'git config --global color.ui auto',
  unless      => 'git config --list --global | grep -q color.ui=auto',
  path        => '/usr/bin',
  logoutput   => 'on_failure',
  user        => 'vagrant',
  environment => 'HOME=/home/vagrant',
  require     => Package['git']
}
```

Comment: That seems more accurate than my answer. +1

Comment: Wouldn't that execute the command everytime when puppet agent runs? Wouldn't it be good to add some `unless` clause there?

Comment: @MarcinPietraszek, that's a good point, updated. Note that many users are doing masterless or immutable infrastructure, so idempotence doesn't always matter.

Comment: @AlexHarvey I would argue that masterless still needs to be idempotent, even if immutable often does not, but I think the real argument here is that a Vagrant instance is an initial provision. Therefore, although idempotence is often unnecessary here, a `vagrant provision` could always be executed via the CLI and then it would be a "nice-to-have". Super minor nitpick, but I think `grep` is in only `/bin` on older systems by the way (regarding your `path` attribute).

Answer (score 1):

The error message shows that `git` is complaining about the `HOME` environment variable not being set.  Other answers describe how you can provide a value for this variable, but that's not necessarily the right way to approach this particular problem.

Consider that the fact that `git` cares about `HOME` suggests that it is trying set configuration at the per-user level.  If that's indeed what you want then fine, but doing it via Puppet seems a bit overkill *vs*. just running the command directly.  On the other hand, if by "--global" you thought you were setting the property at the *system-wide* level, then you are in for a surprise.  `git config --global` sets "global" configuration in the sense of affecting all of *a particular user's* repositories (that do not override it).  System-wide properties are selected via the `--system` option:

```
exec { 'make-git-color':
  command => '/usr/bin/git config --system color.ui auto',
  logoutput => 'on_failure',
  user      => 'vagrant',
  timeout   => 1200,
  require   => Package['git'],
  unless    => 'git config --list --system | grep -q color.ui=auto',
}
```

In that case, you should also consider whether it is appropriate to run the command as user 'vagrant', as it's unclear whether that user has the appropriate authority to modify the system-wide configuration.

You should also consider whether you need such a long timeout.  I don't quite see the circumstance in which you expect that it takes that long to have reasonable confidence that the command has hung.

Comment: These are some good points, and mentioning that this `exec` resource might not be the best way to approach the problem makes me wonder if a better approach would not be to manage the files at `.git/config` and/or `$HOME/.gitconfig` and/or `/etc/gitconfig` with `file` resource(s).

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the work around using file.

```
file { '/home/vagrant/.gitconfig':
    content => "[color]\n        ui = auto",
    owner   => 'vagrant',
    group   => 'vagrant',
    require => Package['git'],
  }
```

but answer which Alex gave above may be the right one. going to try that now :)